# Uninstalling hadoop on Ubuntu 14.04, files/directories left over

Tags: users, hadoop, user-management

I'm trying to completely uninstall Hadoop on my Ubuntu partition (14.04 Trusty Tahr) and am running into an issue I haven't seen before. I completely removed the directory that hadoop was installed to and the `hadoop` user's home directory. I also deleted the user and tried to delete the group but bash said the group didn't exist (although it told me that the group wouldn't have any more members in it once I deleted the user, thought that was wierd).

Now, when trying to find any remaining directories or hadoop-related files - I get the following.

```
$ locate hadoop
/home/hadoop
/opt/hadoop
/opt/hadoop-2.5.1
$ cd /home/hadoop
bash: cd: /home/hadoop: No such file or directory
$ cd /opt/hadoop
bash: cd: /opt/hadoop: No such file or directory
$ cd /opt
$ ls -laF
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  6 root     root     4096 Nov 19 09:54 ./
drwxr-xr-x 23 root     root     4096 Oct  5 23:59 ../
drwxr-xr-x  2 clickpkg clickpkg 4096 Jun 29 23:44 click.ubuntu.com/
drwxr-xr-x  8 jxb      jxb      4096 Nov  4 23:36 eclipse/
drwxr-xr-x  5      501 staff    4096 Mar 18  2014 LightTable/
drwxrwxr-x  9     2000     2000 4096 Mar 18  2014 scala/
```

It says there is still some hadoop left on my system but I can't find it.

1. There is no `hadoop` directory or file in my `/home` or `/opt` directories. What does the above mean?
2. How can I be sure that I removed the `hadoop` group?

Answer (score 2):

locate is not looking directly in the filesystem, it uses a database (or more than one).  The database is updated using the `updatedb` command, which is usually scheduled as a daily cron job.

So I guess in this case, what you are seeing is the indexed information from yesterday. Once the updatedb cron job completes, you should not see these anymore.

You could run `find / -name "*hadoop*` instead, as find looks directly in the filesystem. Since it does the search when you run it, it will take some time to complete.

As for the hadoop group, you can run `sudo grep hadoop /etc/group`, if it does not show anything, then the group has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

**You can uninstall hadoop completely using:**

```
sudo apt-get purge hadoop-2.5.1
```

This `purge` command will remove all packages and configurations related to hadoop from your system.